# In JQuery how can I get the adjacent table cell?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with multiple rows, and each row contains three cells. Each cell contains a textbox, so it looks like this:

```
XXXX   XXXX   XXXX
```

on the keyup event of the first textbox, I want its contents to be copied into the second textbox, but not the third textbox.

my keyup event I can get a reference to the first textbox. Doing .parent() will give me the cell, and if I want, doing .parent() again will give me the row.

What JQuery can I use to get the adjacent textbox?

Comment: What happens if you on the last cell on the row? do you select the first cell in the next row? What happens in the last cell of the last row?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) to get the next sibling, like this:

```
var nextTD = $(this).closest("td").next();
//for your case:
$(this).closest("td").next().find("input").val($(this).val());
```

[`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) works too, [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) is just a bit more flexible, for you could change your markup and it'd still go to the nearest `<td>` parent.

Comment: @SLC - The DOM traversing is a pretty strong area for the library, there are *many* functions for moving around, take a look here: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/

Comment: @SLC - that shouldn't be the case...which version of jQuery are you using?  If it's an older version, stick with `.parent()` for now, or `.parents("td:first")` for the same effect in pre-1.4 versions of jquery.

Answer (score 3):

From the [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) `<td>`, use [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next) to go to the next `<td>`, then [`.children('input')`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) to get the child `<input>` element.

So you end up with something like this in your `keyup` handler.

```
$(this).parent().next().children('input').val( this.value );
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) function a try.  This selects the next sibling of the selected element.